# Restore Photos/Videos Back to iPhone Camera Roll

Tags: iphone, photos, video, photos.app, imovie

If you connect the iPhone to Windows, it comes up in the Computer as a digital camera and lets you Copy/Move photos/videos easily from there, you don’t need to use Photos on the Mac.

If, after connecting like above, you **move** (not copy) all the photos and videos to a folder on the PC, they will obviously disappear from the Camera Roll in iPhone.

**Is it possible to restore the photos and videos back to the Camera Roll?**

I have accidentally moved (instead of copying) lots of photos and videos from my iPhone to a folder Windows 7. It slipped my mind that there were a few **slow-mo videos** which will not play without iPhone/iMovie.

Also, when photos are viewed on iPhone, it displays the location name in the title, which I cannot have once I have moved photos to the computer. In the JPG metadata I only see the Latitude and Longitude saved there.

Thus I prefer to undo this mistake and take photos/videos back to iPhone, is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

I finally resolved this by using iTunes Sync to add photos to an album in iPhone. It is only slightly different as my photos went back to a separate album, not Camera Roll but that’s okay. I noticed that the location name was restored and since it syncs Videos too, I’m sure slow-mo videos would work the way they should.

Also, latest Quicktime player on Mac plays slow-mo videos just like the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Windows but it seems that this may work. If you have the iCloud Control Panel installed you should navigate to your Pictures folder and open the Photo Stream folder. In here you can paste your photos into the Uploads folder and they will automatically sync to your iPhone. Videos cannot be synced through this method, however they can be added using the Photos tab in iTunes.

[Source](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/apple/transfer-photos-from-computer-iphone-ipad-3444903)